# Error with gcloud beta command for streaming assets to bigquery

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, gcloud

This might be a bit bleeding edge but hopefully someone can help. The problem is a catch 22.

So what we're trying to do is create a continuous stream of inventory changes in each GCP project to BigQuery dataset tables that we can create reports from and get a better idea of what we're paying for, what's turned on what's in use what isn't, etc.

> Error: Error running command 'gcloud beta asset feeds create asset_change_feed --project=project_id --pubsub-topic=asset_change_feed': exit status 2. Output: ERROR: (gcloud.beta.asset.feeds.create) argument (--asset-names --asset-types): Must be specified.
>   Usage: gcloud beta asset feeds create FEED_ID --pubsub-topic=PUBSUB_TOPIC (--asset-names=[ASSET_NAMES,...] --asset-types=[ASSET_TYPES,...]) (--folder=FOLDER_ID | --organization=ORGANIZATION_ID | --project=PROJECT_ID) [optional flags]
>     optional flags may be  --asset-names | --asset-types | --content-type |
>                            --folder | --help | --organization | --project

For detailed information on this command and its flags, run:
  gcloud beta asset feeds create --help

Using terraform we tried creating a dataflow job and a pubsub topic called asset_change_feed.

We get an error trying to create the pubsub topic because the `gcloud beta asset feeds create` command wants a parameter that includes all the asset names monitor...

Well... this kind of defeats the purpose. The whole point is to monitor all the asset names that change, appear and disappear. It's like creating a feed that monitors all the new baby names that appear over the next year but the feed command requires that we know them in advance somehow. WTF? What's the point then? Are we re-inventing the wheel here?

We were going by this documentation here:

https://cloud.google.com/asset-inventory/docs/monitoring-asset-changes#creating_a_feed

Comment: I'm not familiar with Cloud Asset Inventory but according to the gcloud command [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/beta/asset/feeds/create) it seems that, if you provide `--asset-types` you are not forced to specify `--asset-names`.

Comment: Nathan, reach me at my email to connect you with someone, it's my username gmail

Comment: Please note that [this](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/beta/asset/export) command is currently in [BETA](https://cloud.google.com/products/#product-launch-stages) and may change without notice, I wouldn't recommend you to use it in production environment.

Comment: Everything is beta with Google lol. This is just collecting asset info anyway. I don't think it would hurt anything.  Turns out @GuillemXercavins was right though. That is the answer if you wanna post it as the answer Guillem.

Comment: @NathanMcKaskle I can connect you with the engineers and your case can change this endpoint. Email me please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the `gcloud beta asset feeds create` [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/beta/asset/feeds/create) it is required to specify **at least one** of `--asset-names` and `--asset-types`:

> At least one of these must be specified:
>
> **--asset-names**=[ASSET_NAMES,…] A comma-separated list of the full names of the assets to receive updates. For example:
>   //compute.googleapis.com/projects/my_project_123/zones/zone1/instances/instance1.
>   See
>   https://cloud.google.com/apis/design/resource_names#full_resource_name
>   for more information.
>
> **--asset-types**=[ASSET_TYPES,…] A comma-separated list of types of the assets types to receive updates. For example:
>   compute.googleapis.com/Disk,compute.googleapis.com/Network See
>   https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/cloud-asset-inventory/overview
>   for all supported asset types.

Therefore, when we don't know the names a priori we can monitor all resources of the desired types by only passing `--asset-types`. You can see the list of supported asset types [here](https://cloud.google.com/asset-inventory/docs/supported-asset-types) or use the [`exportAssets`](https://cloud.google.com/asset-inventory/docs/reference/rest/v1/exportAssets) API method ([`gcloud asset export`](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/asset/export)) to retrieve the types used at an organization, folder or project level.

Comment: This worked of course, the problem is I have no idea what the schema is. I know what the asset inventory resource schema is, but that's apparently not even remotely the same.